# Unable to enumerate USB device on port 2 when connecting Android phone

Tags: 11.10, usb, 64-bit, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit) as a VirtualBox guest on a Win7 64-bit host.

When I plug in my Android Epic4g (Galaxy S) both the host and guest see the device properly, however `lsusb` does not.

When I run `dmesg` I get the following:

```
[  361.664219] usb 1-2: new full speed USB device number 79 using ohci_hcd
[  362.428798] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  363.313782] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

I get the same type of `dmesg` message with the USB 2.0 (ECHI) Controller enabled and disabled for the guest OS.

I'm stuck with this one, can anyone help?

Comment: It's likely a stupid question but... Have you installed guest additions in Ubuntu?.

Comment: @Javier Rivera - Yeah I did the guest additions and the USB expansion pack for Virtual Box.  I also tried to disable ehci_hcd but no luck with that either.  For some reason the VM just cannot enumerate my phone.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to find a solution for this problem? I'm having the same problem after upgrading Samsung Galaxy S2 to ICS 4.0.3.

Comment: @miha - no I gave up.  I even upgraded my BIOS firmware and had no luck.  There is a possibility it is because Im running Ubuntu in a VM and not as the host OS.  In a month or two I'll switch the OS's so linux is the host and win7 is the guest and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

ProfessionalAmateur, I solved my problem. I am using vmware Fusion, but you can perhaps find an equivalent solution for VirtualBox. See my question and my answer to that question here: [Can not connect Android SGSII via USB after ICS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/138844/64225).

Comment: @miha- That is very interesting.  How did you know the exact values?  I'll dig around and see if there is a similiar place to put that for VirtualBox

Comment: I looked at vmware.log in my Ubuntu.vmware directory and I saw how Android device gets connected with code and pid (pid is the last number). I guess pid varies whether you connect mass storage or something else.