# Can not connect Android SGSII via USB after ICS upgrade

Tags: usb, android

I got OTA update for my Samsung Galaxy S2 - Android 4 (ICS). However, the `adb devices` does not show the device. Neither does `lsusb`. I am using ubuntu inside vmware Fusion on a Mac. If I disconnect the device from Ubuntu and use it in OS X, adb devices shows the device.

My udev rule contains the following entry:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

dmesg output does not include string 04e8.

I should note that I tried both USB modes (MTP and PTP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these lines to Ubuntu.vmx file (I believe the last line makes a difference):

```
usb.quirks.device0 = "0x4e8:0x681d skip-reset" # Mass Storage
usb.quirks.device1 = "0x4e8:0x68a9 skip-reset" # Media
usb.quirks.device2 = "0x4e8:0x6877 skip-reset" # Kies
usb.quirks.device3 = "0x4e8:0x6866 skip-reset" # SGS2 ICS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dmesg again and try to grab vendor string that shows up as you connect your device.
Substitute that ID for the one you currently have.

If nothing shows up, make sure Development mode is enabled on your S2.

Comment: Development mode (USB debugging) is enabled. It is working from host OS (OS X Lion). It was working from Ubuntu before I upgraded to ICS. dmesg and lsusb outputs:
miha@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: And dmesg: `[ 3751.650501] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 3763.141707] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 46
[ 3778.252927] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 3778.936251] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 47
[ 3794.048386] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1`