# Virtual Box: Problems using USB Phone

Tags: usb, virtualbox, android, development, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can not connect Android SGSII via USB after ICS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138560/can-not-connect-android-sgsii-via-usb-after-ics-upgrade)

I'm not completely sure if this is the right part of stackexchange to ask this question, so if I'm in the wrong place, I'm sorry.

So, I am trying to set up a Ubuntu VM for Android Development. Therefore I want to use my phone inside my VM for debugging my Applications.

After 2 days of struggling with Virtual Box' USB forwarding (it always told me the device was busy), I found out that using USB 3.0 ports was a problem.
Now at least Virtual Box isn't complaining anymore, but now I am getting error messages inside my VM (dmesg):

```
[ 2680.841115] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

I get these messages every second. lsusb is not listing my device. Can anyone explain the reason i get these errors to me?

Currently I have disabled USB 2.0 in Virtual Box. I installed the extension pack.

My Configuration:

```
Host: Windows 7 x64
Guest: Ubuntu 12.04
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S with Android 4.0
Virtual Box: 4.1.22
```

I hope you have an answer to my problem, because right now I have to export all my Apps as APK and install the to my device manually without the ability to view debug logs.

If you need more Information or additional Logfiles, please say so.

Edit:
Just to be clear: I don't use vmware (because all the possible dublicates referred to a vmware question) so, correct me if I'm wrong, I can't use the solution provided there.

As of now I am using adb over tcp to debug my Applications in Virtual Box, but I don't want to continue using this, because now others don't even need physical access to my phone to run adb commants (as root user!) on my phone.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/138844/83046

Comment: Hey! @Alex! Well... I was about to say "welcome to askubuntu" but as we can see those guys already said that in their own way... However. I also suggest you to run a search on the site for similar questions and see if some of their answers are helpful for you. If not then drop back an edit (or new question if already closed) including the questions/steps that you already tried in order not to be welcomed with a "possible duplicate" or other nonsense reason of their reduced menu of possibilities for question closure. They already started voting to close it, so ... Hurry up man!!! (Good luck?)

Comment: **No dupe** they will not be able to do anything on .vmx files when using Virtual Box.